# Does the .NET Core portability analyzer identify native methods we can't call?

Tags: .net-core

We make a number of native method calls such as CreateDC() & DeleteDC(). THey are not listed in "not supported."

Does this mean they are supported? Or does the portability analyzer not scan these?

Comment: It is not practical to analyze [DllImport].  Calling these functions on Linux or macOS works as well as anybody can imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) and the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport), it only analyzes the .NET api only. Native methods are ignored.

Comment: Where did you see that? I read the documentation and it was silent on if the calls in my DLL that it checks are only managed code calls, or all calls. Or I missed it.

Comment: The documentation states that it checks .NET API, (CreateDC, for example, is a win32/gdi function). Inspecting the source code (https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport) you can see that the analyzer uses .NET reflection and metadata analysis to detect offending API.